# Finite fields - quadratic extensions

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field

Let $F_q$ be a finite field of $\operatorname{char}F\neq2$.
suppose $a_1$,$a_2$,...,$a_q$ are the elements in $F_q$.

1. show there exists $i$ such that for any $j$ $a_i\neq a_j^2$.
2. compute the degree of the extension $F_q(\sqrt{a_1},...,\sqrt{a_q})/F_q$.

for the first question, I supposed not, then for any $i$ there exists $j$ s.t. $a_i=a_j^2$.
then $f:F_q\to F_q, f(x)=x^2$ is an automorphism. so we can arrange $F_q$ elements to couples (except 0,1-so consinder them a couple). but then $2\mid q$ and this is a contradiction. Does it work?

I'm stuck with the second question.

Thank you in adavance.

Comment: What do you mean by an automorphism? A bijection? That you actually get, because your contrapositive assumption does show that $f$ is surjective, hence bijective (as a function from a finite set to itself). But I don't understand the talk about *couples*. It sounds like you want to mimic the famous simple proof that every finite group of even order has an element of order two, but I don't see the couples?

Comment: In your proof of the first question you are leaving out some important intermediate steps, like why the assumption implies that $f$ is automorphism (why should it be additive?), what you mean by arranging the elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$ to couples (How is this done precisely?) and why this implies $2\mid q$. Also, as far as I can tell, you cannot deduce that $f$ is an automorphism, but only a bijection (but this will turn out to be enough by looking at the images of $1$ and $-1$).

Comment: But I give you a few hints: 1) What about $f(-1)$? Can $f$ really be a bijection? 2) What can you say about the fields $F_q(\sqrt{a_i})$, when we adjoin a single square root?

Comment: I wanted to attach each element it's root

Comment: But what do you attach to the root then? You don't get a couple, you get a sequence $a,\sqrt a,\sqrt{\sqrt a},\ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, then the function I mentioned is surjective (by assumption) and a bijection since Fq is finite. But then f(1)=f(-1)=1, and it's a contradiction because in Fq 1 isn't equals to -1.
for the second question,
F_q(√ai) isomorphic to Fq iff sqrt(ai) is in F, else it's isomorphic to Fq^2, which also has the same char.

Comment: So far so good!. Then what happens, if you adjoin all those square roots?

Comment: as there is a primitive elemt in Fq s.t. Fq=Fp(ai), it's sufficient to add sqrt(ai) to Fp in order to get Fq(sqrt(a1),...sqrt(aq)), then I think that the extension degree is 2.

Comment: Correct. Well done! (too bad I had already upvoted)